# HDMI monitor cuts off DP Monitor on a MacBook Pro 2015 13'

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, displayport

I have two monitors Dell UltraSharp U2719DX and Dell UltraSharp U2715H.

I have a MacBook Pro 2015 13-inch that still works. My U2719DX is plugged into my Mac via DisplayPort (monitor) to mini DisplayPort (macbook) and works just fine.

Then my U2715H plugs into via HDMI (monitor) to HDMI (macbook) and once that happens, my U2719DX cuts out and the HDMI monitor is the only one displaying anything besides the macbook.

What am I doing wrong?